# Howto prevent Boostrap 4 Select-Picker from opening

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I have a Bootstrap 4 with [Bootstrap-select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) plugin and two buttons:

```
<div>
    <button id="disableButtonId">Disable selectpicker<button/>
    <button id="enableButtonId">Enable selectpicker<button/>
    <select id="selectpickerId" class="selectpicker" multiple title="Select option">
        <option value=1>@Option 1</option>
        <option value=2>@Option 2</option>
        <option value=3>@Option 3</option>
        <option value=4>@Option 4</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I need to prevent selectpicker from opening on one button click and revert state to normal on another button click.

That doesn't work:

```
<script>
     $('#disableButtonId').on('click', function (e) {
          $('#selectpickerId').on('mousedown', function (e) { 
               e.preventDefault(); 
          });           
     });

     $('#enableButtonId').on('click', function (e) {
          $('#selectpickerId').off('mousedown');           
     });
</script>
```

Than is not also working `$('#selectpickerId').on('click'...`

Custom boostrap-select event is working, but results in long lags:

```
$('#disableButtonId').on('click', function (e) {
     $('#selectpickerId').on('show.bs.select', function (e) { 
          $('#selectpickerId').selectpicker('toggle'); 
     });           
});
```

Separate close method `.selectpicker('close')` is available only in [v1.14.0-beta](https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/issues/1893#issuecomment-625305976) for today so I cannot test it.

I cannot use `disabled` attribute for `selectpicker` because I need it's value to be posted to server.

So any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of disabling select-box you can disable `dropdown-toggle` button whenever user click on disable button i.e : `$(".dropdown-toggle").prop('disabled',true)` and enable it when enable button is clicked.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('#disableButtonId').on('click', function(e) {
  $(".dropdown-toggle").prop('disabled', true); //disable button
});

$('#enableButtonId').on('click', function(e) {
  $(".dropdown-toggle").prop('disabled', false); //enable it
});
//for testing(to know if value gets pass or not if disabled.)
//select some value inside selectpicker -> click on disable button ->then click on save
$('[name=save]').on('click', function(e) {
  console.log($(this).closest("form").serialize())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<form>
  <button id="disableButtonId" type="button">Disable selectpicker</button>
  <button id="enableButtonId" type="button">Enable selectpicker</button>
  <select id="selectpickerId" class="selectpicker" multiple name="select" title="Select option">
    <option value=1>@Option 1</option>
    <option value=2>@Option 2</option>
    <option value=3>@Option 3</option>
    <option value=4>@Option 4</option>
  </select>
  <button type="button" name="save">Save</button>
</form>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Working like a charm, thank you. 

BTW: I dont see any element with `dropdown-toggle` className. I suppose using  `class="selectpicker` injects some new elements on a page, right? Where can I read more info about that (maybe some docs section)?

Comment: Hi, selectpicker plugin generates many elements dynamically and you can find these elements when you inspect your *elements tab* in browser . I am not sure if this is there inside docs or not .